# Ideas for projects with Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I am not sure if my question is appropriate for here, if not please tell me and excuse me, I will delete it.

I am interested in developing web applications with PHP and currently I am learning how to use Symfony2 with Twig and Doctrine2. Could you please give me some ideas for simple and interesting projects which I can try to make, so that I could learn and remember things better, because I find out that when I only read, I don't remember much of the stuff.

Comment: Practical **Symphony**. Argh....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to implement something that you already know how to. The idea is that thinking about both *what* to do and *how* to do it is overwhelming. The common advice is to implement a blog because everybody knows what it is. It might be a task manager as well.

Implementing something your or somebody else really need is even better, because you'll solve a real problem and it will be more rewarding.

Answer (score 1):

This framework can be applied for everything - so there can't be one single idea.

You should just start using it...

If you need ideas to implement - ask your friends, if they need a personal website, portfolio, forum and just do it. Then - add ability to edit its content. With security, of course.

Applying your knowledge on practice - this is the only right way to increase your skills.

Just do something :)